# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe

Tags: java, python-2.7, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to query a table from Hive using iPython. Below is what my code looks like.

```
sqlc = HiveContext(sc)
sqlc.sql("ADD JAR s3://x/y/z/jsonserde.jar")
```

I first create a new hive context and second try to add the jar above. Below is the error message I get.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.sql:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

How else do I add this jar to Spark classpath?

Comment: You receive that error because you haven't add your library in your SparkContext when you started iPython.

Comment: PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython bin/pyspark --master local[1] --jars [path/to/jar].jar --driver-class-path [path/to/jar].jar

Comment: So did it solve your problem?

Comment: ok then please accept the answer and upvote what i told you solved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because you haven't add your library in your SparkContext when you started iPython.

To do so you'll need to run your shell doing the following :

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython bin/pyspark --master local[1] --jars [path/to/jar].jar --driver-class-path [path/to/jar].jar
```

**NB:** Specifying the `--jars` won't be enough for now considering the [SPARK-5185](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5185).